# How do pass an event to other object?

Tags: java, event-handling, awt

I have a textBox and when the An keyevent is done i want my menu to get highlighted So i am looking for event passing from the textfield to the menu. So, is there any way to that ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I dont want menu to get focused but highlighted as i always want the event to come to the textfield first

Comment: please edit your question rather than mentioning in the comment area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [KeyListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addKeyListener%28java.awt.event.KeyListener%29) to the textBox, and in [keyPressed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) method you can implement the logic to manipulate the menu based on the criteria.

Comment: Yes i tried that already setSlection is not working to select the menu :(

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's "bad way", but try to make your menu class, extending old one, and add there some public method (with your highlighting logic) invoked by action listener in text filed